# Run "Create new task" WINAPI

Tags: winapi

I need to run "Create new task" program from my applications, the same as you can run from task manager.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `CreateProcess ()` API.

I suggest you look at the documentation, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will allow you to load an application by its name, and the rest is taken care of by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the Run dialog? This code will open the Windows run dialog. *Warning: this accesses a Windows API via ordinal, not via name. This is generally a sign of doing something undocumented that may or may not work in future Windows releases.*

```
// MS Run dialog
typedef void (__stdcall* lpfnMSRun)(HWND, HICON, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, int);
static lpfnMSRun MSRun = NULL;

bool DisplayRunDialog()
{
  if ((MSRun == NULL) && (emergeLibGlobals::GetShell32DLL()))
  {
    MSRun = (lpfnMSRun)GetProcAddress(emergeLibGlobals::GetShell32DLL(), (LPCSTR) 61);
  }

  if (MSRun)
  {
    MSRun(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Just a couple of notes about this - `emergeLibGlobals::GetShell32DLL()` is an internal method that calls `LoadLibrary` on shell32.dll and returns its HMODULE. You can just call `LoadLibrary` directly. Also, if your compiler supports C++11 you can replace `NULL` with `nullptr` across the board.

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2734/Using-the-Windows-RunFile-dialog-The-documented-an) claims to have a documented way to do the same thing, but I haven't tried it so I can't guarantee it'll work.

Comment: No. Don't do this. Just call ShellExecuteEx if you want to replicate that functionality.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there any particular reason why, aside from the fact that this is undocumented? I'm curious, since I pulled this code directly from a codebase I maintain. If it's bad code, I'd like to know so I can deal with it.

Comment: Do you need another reason

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My codebase is a shell replacement, so we're already stuck doing undocumented stuff (MS is not friendly toward replacement shells). So yes, I would need another reason.

Comment: That's really your issue and unrelated to the q

Comment: I would still disagree with you; if an undocumented function is acceptable in one app, I would usually consider it acceptable in another. But I feel it's just a difference of opinion at this point so I'll drop it. Thanks!

Comment: If that was so why did you feel compelled to describe what your app did?

Comment: Because "if it's acceptable in one app, it's acceptable in another" still requires me to provide a case where it's acceptable to prove that it would be acceptable for op.

Comment: Well I'm pleased that you feel happy to have proved that using undocumented APIs is a reasonable solution to any problem. I question your logic.